# Create a doubly Linked List but can't print out the result

Tags: java

```
/**This class implements a doubly linked list of characters in Java. 
 * The instance variables head and tail are initially null. 
 * As elements are added head points to the first element on the
 * list and tail points to the last element. 
 * Each node on the list is of type DoubleNode. 
 * Each DoubleNode holds a pointer to the previous 
 * node and a pointer to the next node in the list.
 * @param head       Keeps track of the first node of the list. Null if nothing.
 * @param tail       Keeps track of the last node of the list. Null if nothing.
 */    

public class DoublyLinkedList {

        //data field
        DoubleNode head;
        DoubleNode tail;

        /**Constructor
         * Precondition: The object to be created is casted as DoublyLinkedList
         * Postcondition:Constructs a new DoublyLinkedList object with head and        
               tail as null
             * Best case and worst case are the same: theta(1)
             * Afterwards a new null list comes into existence
             */
        public DoublyLinkedList(){
            head = null;
            tail = null;
        }

        /**Mutator
         * @param c  The character to be added
         * Precondition: The character is an uppercase 
         * or lowercase letter (in the range 'A' ... 'Z' or 'a' ... 'z') 
         * Postcondition:A character node containing the character 
         * c will be added to the end
         * Best case and worst case are the same: theta(1)
         */
        public void addCharAtEnd(char c){
            if(this.isEmpty()) {//When no node in list so far
                head = new DoubleNode(null,null,c);
                tail = head;
            }
            else{//More than one node exist(s)
              DoubleNode endNode = new DoubleNode(tail,null,c);
              tail.setNext(endNode);
              tail = endNode;
            }

        }

        /**Deletes the first occurence of the character c from the list
         * @param c the character want to find and then deleted
         * @return True if a deletion occurred and false otherwise
         * Precondition: The character is an uppercase 
         * or lowercase letter (in the range 'A' ... 'Z' or 'a' ... 'z') 
         * Postcondition:Afterwards the list will abandon the first occurence of
         * the character c from the list or won't change(if c not presented)
         * Best case: O(1)(theta(1),when node containing c happens to be the head) 
         * Worst case: went over the whole list. Theta(n)
         * Average: theta(n)
         */
        public boolean deleteChar(char c){
        if(isEmpty()) return false;
        else {
            for(DoubleNode current = head; current != null; current = `enter code here`current.getNext()){
                if(current.getC() == c){
                    if(current == head && tail != null){//More than one `enter code here`node and the node to be deleted is the head
                        head = head.getNext();
                        head.setPrev(null);
                        }

                    if(current == head && tail == null){//There is only `enter code here`one node
                        head = tail = null;

                    }
                    if(current == tail){//More than one node and the `enter code here`node to be deleted is the tail
                      tail  = tail.getPrev();
                      tail.setNext(null);
                    }
                    else{//The node is between two more nodes in the list
                        DoubleNode previous = current.getPrev();
                        current.getNext().setPrev(previous);
                        previous.setNext(current.getNext());

                    }
                }
                    return true;

            }
            return false;//After looping still nothing found
        }
        }

        /**Mutator
         * Precondition: The character is an uppercase 
         * or lowercase letter (in the range 'A' ... 'Z' or 'a' ... 'z') 
         * Postconditions: a character node containing the 
         * character c will be added to the start
         * @param c  The character to be added
         * Best case and worst case are the same: theta(1)
         */
        public void addCharAtFront(char c){
            if(this.isEmpty()) {
                head = new DoubleNode(null,null,c);
                tail = head;
            }
            else{
             DoubleNode newHead = new DoubleNode(null,head,c);
             head.setPrev(newHead);
             head = newHead;

        }
        }

        /**Count the nodes in the list
         * Precondition: The instance used to invoke the method exists
         * Postcondition: Return the int number of the node in that
         * instance, leaving everything unchanged.
         * @return the number of nodes
         * Could be no cases(nothing in list)
         * If there are node(s)Best and Worst case: theta(n)(go over the list)
         */
        public int countNodes(){
            int counter = 0;
            for(DoubleNode current = this.head; current != null; current = `enter code here`current.getNext()){
                counter++;
            }
            return counter;
        }

        /**Remove and return the character at the beginning of the doubly linked list.
         * Precondition: The instance used to invoke the method exists and 
         * there is at least one node in the instance(if not, returning ']')
         * Postcondition: Remove and return the character at the beginning 
         * of the doubly linked list
         * @return the character stored in the deleted node
         * Best and worst case: theta(1)
            */
            public char removeCharFromFront(){
                char c;
                if(isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Empty list, returning ']'");
                    return ']';
                }
                else {
                    if(head == tail){//There is only one node
                        c = head.getC();
                        head = null;
                        tail = null;
                        return c;

                    }
                    else{
                        c = head.getC();
                        head = head.getNext();
                        head.setPrev(null);// line 156?
                        return c;
                    }
                }

            }

        /**Remove and return the character at the end of the doubly linked list
         * Precondition: The instance used to invoke the method exists and
         *  there is node in the instance(if not, returning ']')
         * Postcondition: Remove and return the character at the end of the 
         * doubly linked list.
         * @return the character stored in the deleted node
         * Best and worst case: theta(1)
            */
            public char removeCharAtEnd(){
                char c;
                if(isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Empty list, returning ']'");
                    return ']';
                }
                else {
                    if(head == tail){//There is only one node
                        c = head.getC();
                        head = null;
                        tail = null;
                        return c;

                    }
                    else{
                        c = tail.getC();
                        tail.getPrev().setNext(null);
                        tail = tail.getPrev();
                        return c;
                    }

                }
            }

        /**Check if the list is empty
         * Precondition: The instance used to invoke the method exists
         * Postcondition: Returns true if the list is empty false otherwise,
         * leaving everything unchanged
         * @return true if the list is empty false otherwise
         * Best and worst case: Theta(1)
         */
        public boolean isEmpty(){
            if(head == null)
            return true;
            else return false;
        }

        /**Reverse the whole list by changing the pointer
         * Precondition: The instance used to invoke the method exists
         * Postcondition: The whole list will be reversed
         * Could be no cases
         * Best and worst is theta(n)
         */
        public void reverse(){
            if(isEmpty())
                System.out.println("No node in the list");
            else{
                DoubleNode newTail = head;
                head = tail;

                for (DoubleNode current = tail; current != null; current = `enter code here`current.getPrev()){
                        current.setNext(current.getPrev());
                        current.setPrev(current.getNext());
                    }
                tail = newTail;

                }

                }


        /**toString methods overriding the one in java.lang.object
         * Precondition: The instance used to invoke the method exists
         * Postcondition: return the characters in list as String, leaving
         * everything else unchanged.
         * @return the String expression of the characters stored in the list
         * Best case and worst case are the same: theta(n)
         */

        public String toString(){
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            if(isEmpty())
                return new String("No node in the list");
            DoubleNode current = new DoubleNode();
            for(current = this.head; current != null; current = `enter code here`current.getNext()){
                sb.append(String.valueOf(current.getC()));
                System.out.println(sb);

            }
            System.out.println(sb);
            return new String(sb);
        }

        /**Test the DoublyLinkedList class
         * @param args command-line arguments 
         * Initiate two nodes using different constructor. Test the above 
         * method.
         */
    public static void main(String a[]) {

            DoublyLinkedList list = new DoublyLinkedList();
            list.addCharAtEnd('H');
            list.addCharAtEnd('e');
            list.addCharAtEnd('l');
            list.addCharAtEnd('l');
            list.addCharAtEnd('o');
            System.out.println(list);
            System.out.println("Deleting l");
            list.deleteChar('l');
            System.out.println(list);
            System.out.println("Deleting H");
            list.deleteChar('H');
            System.out.println(list);
            System.out.println("Deleting o");
            list.deleteChar('o');
            System.out.println(list);
            System.out.println("Deleting e");
            list.deleteChar('e');
            System.out.println(list);
            System.out.println("Deleting l");
            list.deleteChar('l');
            System.out.println(list);
            list.addCharAtFront('o');
            list.addCharAtFront('l');
            list.addCharAtFront('l');
            list.addCharAtFront('e');
            list.addCharAtFront('H');
            System.out.println(list);

            System.out.println(list.countNodes());

            System.out.println("Popping everything");
            while(!list.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println(list.removeCharFromFront());//line 294?
            }

            list.addCharAtFront('o');
            list.addCharAtFront('l');
            list.addCharAtFront('l');
            list.addCharAtFront('e');
            list.addCharAtFront('H');

            System.out.println("Popping everything from the end");
            while(!list.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println(list.removeCharAtEnd());
            }
            System.out.println(list.countNodes());

            list.addCharAtEnd('o');
            list.addCharAtEnd('l');
            list.addCharAtEnd('l');
            list.addCharAtEnd('e');
            list.addCharAtEnd('H');

            list.reverse();
            System.out.println(list);

            list.reverse();
            System.out.println(list);

        }

    }

    public class DoubleNode {
        // data field
        private DoubleNode p;
        private DoubleNode n;
        private char c;

        /**
         * Constructor with parameters to initialize instance variables with given p, c, n
         * Preconditions: p, c, n should be casted correctly to be the right instances
         * Postcondition: Afterwards generates a new node with double pointers 
         * Best case and worst case are the same: theta(1)
         */
        public DoubleNode(DoubleNode initialp, DoubleNode initialn, char initialc) {
            DoubleNode p = initialp;
            DoubleNode n = initialn;
            char c = initialc;
        }

        /**Constructor without parameters
         * Precondition: Initialize instance variables with unspecified value
         * So no pre.
         * Postcondition: A new node with null pointers come into existence
         * Best case and worst case are the same: theta(1)
         */
        public DoubleNode() {
            this.p = null;
            this.n = null;
        }
        /**Access to get the reference to previous node in specific node
         * @return the reference to the previous node. Null if nothing
         * Precondition: the instance used to invoke the method does exist
         * Postcondition: Return the previous pointer in current instance while doesn't change the node
         * Best case and worst case are the same: theta(1)
         */
        public DoubleNode getPrev() {
            return p;
        }

        /**Mutator to change the pointer pointing the previous node
         * @param p the value of new previous pointer of that node
         * Precondition: the instance used to invoke the method does exist. n is `enter code here`created to be DoubleNode.
         * Postcondition: Set the previous pointer in Node while leave other things `enter code here`the same. 
         * Best case and worst case are the same: theta(1)
         */
        public void setPrev(DoubleNode p) {
            this.p = p;
        }

        /**Access to get the reference to next node in specific node
         * @return the reference to the next node. Null if nothing
         * Precondition: the instance used to invoke the method does exist
         * Postcondition: Return the next pointer in current instance while doesn't change the node
         * Best case and worst case are the same: theta(1)
         */
        public DoubleNode getNext() {
            return n;
        }

        /**Mutator to change the pointer pointing the next node
         * @param n the value of new next pointer of that node
         * Precondition: the instance used to invoke the method does exist. n is `enter code here`created to be DoubleNode
         * Postcondition: Set the next pointer in Node while leave other things the `enter code here`same. 
         * Best case and worst case are the same: theta(1)
         */
        public void setNext(DoubleNode n) {
            this.n = n;
        }

        /**Access to get the character in specific node
         * @return the character in the node
         * Precondition: the instance used to invoke the method does exist
         * Postcondition: Return the character in current instance while doesn't `enter code here`change the node
         * Best case and worst case are the same: theta(1)
         */
        public char getC() {
            return c;
        }

        /**Mutator to change the character in specific node
         * @param c the value to be changed to
         * Precondition: the instance used to invoke the method does exist. The `enter code here`character is an uppercase 
         * or lowercase letter (in the range 'A' ... 'Z' or 'a' ... 'z') 
         * Postcondition: Reset the character in the Node while leave pointers the `enter code here`same
         * Best case and worst case are the same: theta(1)
         */
        public void setC(char c) {
            this.c = c;
        }

        /**toString methods overriding the one in java.lang.object
         * @return the String expression of the character stored in the node
         * Precondition: the instance used to invoke the method does exist
         * Postcondition: return the character as String in the node while dosen't `enter code here`change anything else
         * Best case and worst case are the same: theta(1)
         */
        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(c);
        }

        /**Test the DoubleNode class
         * @param args command-line arguments 
         * Initiate two nodes using different constructor. Test the methods above
         */
        public static void main(String[] args){
            DoubleNode dllNode = new DoubleNode();
            StringBuffer test = new StringBuffer();
            System.out.println("Test: "+dllNode);
            dllNode.setC('H');
            dllNode.setNext(null);
            dllNode.setPrev(null);
            System.out.println("Test2: "+dllNode);

        }

    }
```

The result should be:
Hello
Deleting l
Helo
Deleting H
elo
Deleting o
el
Deleting e
l
Deleting l
No node in the list
Hello
5
Popping everything
H
e
l
l
o
Popping everything from the end
o
l
l
e
H
0
Hello
olleH

But I can't print out the linked list, and there is also an error as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at DoublyLinkedList.removeCharFromFront(DoublyLinkedList.java:156)
at DoublyLinkedList.main(DoublyLinkedList.java:294)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to fix the bugs in this homework problem for you, since you won't learn if I give you the solution, but here are a few suggestions:

1. `addCharAtEnd` has comments indicating that, if the list is not empty, more than one node must exist.  Are one-node lists really disallowed?
2. Please just change the body of `isEmpty` to `return head == null;`.  There is no reason to test on a boolean expression with an if statement and then return the exact value of that expression.
3. You should add a method that walks through the linked list, makes sure that all the pointers are correct (the node prior to `head` is `null`, the node after `tail` is `null`, and if A's next node is B, then B's previous node is A), and prints the characters in the list.  Then you should add calls to that method after every method that mutates (i.e. changes) the list.  Alternatively, you can step through your code in a debugger and inspect the list after every operation.  Take out the calls after you hand in your assignment, but trace printing like this can be a useful debugging technique.  Of course there are techniques that are better than trace printing in some cases, and trace printing can change the behavior of a system, but in this case it's perfectly fine.

The third one is really important as you become a better programmer.  Being able to debug your code, and compare your assumptions to what actually happened, will help you find a lot of bugs.  Also, try edge cases (odd, strange, or unexpected inputs) to see if your code handles them nicely.  And you should look into unit testing frameworks, such as [JUnit](http://junit.sourceforge.net/) as a way to find bugs almost automatically.  JUnit is a nice framework that is even built in to [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/), making it extra convenient.